# How do I visualise / plot a decision tree in Apache Spark (PySpark 1.4.1)?

Tags: apache-spark, plot, decision-tree, dtreeviz

I am using Apache Spark Mllib 1.4.1 (PySpark, the python implementation of Spark) to generate a decision tree based on LabeledPoint data I have. The tree generates correctly and I can print it to the terminal (extract the rules as this user calls it [How to extract rules from decision tree spark MLlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782288/how-to-extract-rules-from-decision-tree-spark-mllib)) using:

```
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier( ... )
print(model.toDebugString()
```

But what I want to do is visualize or plot the decision tree rather than printing it to the terminal. Is there any way I can plot the decision tree in PySpark or maybe I can save the decision tree data and use R to plot it? Thanks!

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Did you manage to plot your DT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is this project [Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark](https://github.com/hechemeljed/Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark) for visualizing decision tree model

It has two steps

- Parse Spark Decision Tree output to a [JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hechemeljed/Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark/master/data/structure.json) format.
- Use the JSON file as an input to a [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) visualization.

For the parser check [Dt.py](https://github.com/hechemeljed/Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark/blob/master/DT.py#L51-L64)

The input to the function `def tree_json(tree)` is your models `toDebugString()`

Answer from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37563130/2104970)

Answer (score 4):

We just released [dtreeviz](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) 1.1 version, with support for Decision Trees from Spark. You can visualize a lot of things, like the whole tree, just the prediction path, leaf information like number of samples or criterion.

You can check many visualizations in this [notebook](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/notebooks/dtreeviz_spark_visualisations.ipynb)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Though this is a little old post, just to provide my answer so that others coming to this post from now on can be benefitted.

Alternatively you can use **"graphviz"** python Package for use in PySpark. It will print the decision tree model into a neat tree structure rather than usual if loop structure.

More details can be found in this link : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz