# Spark ML: How does DecisionTreeClassificatonModel know about the tree weights?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'd like to get the weight for the tree nodes from a saved (or unsaved) `DecisionTreeClassificationModel`. However I can't find anything remotely resembling that.

How does the model actually perform the classification not knowing any of those. Below are the Params that are saved in the model:

```
{"class":"org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel"
"timestamp":1551207582648
"sparkVersion":"2.3.2"
"uid":"DecisionTreeClassifier_4ffc94d20f1ddb29f282"
"paramMap":{
"cacheNodeIds":false
"maxBins":32
"minInstancesPerNode":1
"predictionCol":"prediction"
"minInfoGain":0.0
"rawPredictionCol":"rawPrediction"
"featuresCol":"features"
"probabilityCol":"probability"
"checkpointInterval":10
"seed":956191873026065186
"impurity":"gini"
"maxMemoryInMB":256
"maxDepth":2
"labelCol":"indexed"
}
"numFeatures":1
"numClasses":2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`treeWeights`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=treeweights#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.treeWeights):

> `treeWeights`
>
> Return the weights for each tree
>
> New in version 1.5.0.

So

> How does the model actually perform the classification not knowing any of those.

The weights are stored, just not as a part of the metadata. If you have `model`

```py
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassificationModel

model: RandomForestClassificationModel = ...
```

and save it to disk

```py
path: str = ...

model.save(path)
```

you'll see that the writer creates `treesMetadata` subdirectory. If you load the content (default writer uses Parquet):

```py
import os

trees_metadata = spark.read.parquet(os.path.join(path, "treesMetadata"))
```

you'll see following structure:

```py
trees_metadata.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- treeID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- metadata: string (nullable = true)
 |-- weights: double (nullable = true)
```

where `weights` column contains the weight of tree identified by `treeID`.

Similarly node data is stored in the `data` subdirectory (see for example [Extract and Visualize Model Trees from Sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53123840/10465355)):

```
spark.read.parquet(os.path.join(path, "data")).printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)
 |-- impurity: double (nullable = true)
 |-- impurityStats: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- gain: double (nullable = true)
 |-- leftChild: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rightChild: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- split: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- featureIndex: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- leftCategoriesOrThreshold: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- numCategories: integer (nullable = true)
```

Equivalent information (minus tree data and tree weights) is available for `DecisionTreeClassificationModel` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link to the documentation is for RandomForests and not for the basic DecisionTree. However with the approach of saving the model and reading back the data in parquet files I should be able to get to that of the DecisionTree the same way

Comment: Indeed, I focused on tree weights. In such case I don't think this really answers the question - could you unaccept it, so it can be deleted? TIA

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your approach was what I was looking for anyway