# Displaying rules of decision tree modelled in pyspark ml library

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am new to spark. I have modeled decision tree using Dataframe based API i.e. pyspark.ml. I want to display rules of decision tree similar to what we get in RDD based API(spark.mllib) in spark using **toDebugString**.
I have read the documentation and could not find how to display the rules. Is there any other way?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614077/how-to-print-the-decision-path-rules-used-to-predict-sample-of-a-specific-row/51750088#51750088 answers your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract rules from decision tree spark MLlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782288/how-to-extract-rules-from-decision-tree-spark-mllib)

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 2.0 both [DecisionTreeClassificationModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel.toDebugString) and [DecisionTreeRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel.toDebugString) provide `toDebugString` methods.