# How to print the decision path / rules used to predict sample of a specific row in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

How to print the decision path of a specific sample in a Spark DataFrame?

```python
Spark Version: '2.3.1'
```

The below code prints the decision path of the whole model, how to make it print a decision path of a specific sample? For example, the decision path of the row where tagvalue ball equals 2

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('demo')\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .getOrCreate()

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ball': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'keep': [4, 5, 6, 7],
    'hall': [8, 9, 10, 11],
    'fall': [12, 13, 14, 15],
    'mall': [16, 17, 18, 10],
    'label': [21, 31, 41, 51]
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df = df.withColumn("mono_ID", monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window().orderBy("mono_ID")
df = df.select(row_number().over(w).alias("tagvalue"), col("*"))

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=['ball', 'keep', 'hall', 'fall'], outputCol='features')
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label')

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assembler, dtc]).fit(df)
transformed_pipeline = pipeline.transform(df)

#ml_pipeline = pipeline.stages[1]

result = transformed_pipeline.filter(transformed_pipeline.tagvalue == 2)
result.select('tagvalue', 'prediction').show()


+--------+----------+
|tagvalue|prediction|
+--------+----------+
|       2|      31.0|
+--------+----------+
```

The above prints the `prediction` of tagvalue `2`. Now I would like the decision path in the algorithm that led to that answer of that tag value rather than the whole model.

I am aware of the following but that prints the whole model decision path rather than a specific model.

```python
ml_pipeline = pipeline.stages[1]
ml_pipeline.toDebugString
```

The equivalent of that exists in [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html) learn, what is the equivalence in spark ?

### Update 1:

If you would run the following code in scikit learn, it will print the decision path for that specific sample, here is a snippet straight out of the website.

```python
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
children_left = estimator.tree_.children_left
children_right = estimator.tree_.children_right
feature = estimator.tree_.feature
threshold = estimator.tree_.threshold

# First let's retrieve the decision path of each sample. The decision_path
# method allows to retrieve the node indicator functions. A non zero element of
# indicator matrix at the position (i, j) indicates that the sample i goes
# through the node j.

node_indicator = estimator.decision_path(X_test)

# Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

leave_id = estimator.apply(X_test)

# Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
# a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

sample_id = 0
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                    node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
for node_id in node_index:
    if leave_id[sample_id] != node_id:
        continue

    if (X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
        threshold_sign = "<="
    else:
        threshold_sign = ">"

    print("decision id node %s : (X_test[%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)" %
          (node_id, 
           sample_id, 
           feature[node_id],
           X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]], 
           threshold_sign,
           threshold[node_id]))
```

THe output will be like this

> Rules used to predict sample 0:  decision id node 4 : (X_test[0, -2]
>   (= 5.1) > -2.0)

Comment: Pyspark doesn't have this functionality. Do you need help on how to implement a way to do it using the information from `.toDebugString()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed your dataframe just slightly so that we could ensure we could see different features in the explanations
I changed the Assembler to use a feature_list, so we have easy access to that later
changes below:

```py
#change1: ball goes from [0,1,2,3] ->[0,1,1,3] so we can see other features in explanations
#change2: added in multiple paths to the same prediction
#change3: added in a categorical variable
#change3: feature_list so we can re-use those indicies easily later
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ball': [0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3],
    'keep': [4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 7],
    'hall': [8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 6, 10, 11],
    'fall': [12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 12, 14, 15],
    'mall': [16, 17, 18, 10, 10, 16, 18, 10],
    'wall': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','c','e'],
    'label': [21, 31, 41, 51, 51, 51, 21, 31]
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df = df.withColumn("mono_ID", monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window().orderBy("mono_ID")
df = df.select(row_number().over(w).alias("tagvalue"), col("*"))

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='wall', outputCol='wallIndex')
encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol='wallIndex', outputCol='wallVec')

#i added this line so feature replacement later is easy because of the indices
features = ['ball','keep','wallVec','hall','fall']
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=features, outputCol='features')
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label')

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, encoder, assembler, dtc]).fit(df)
transformed_pipeline = pipeline.transform(df)
```

Below is a method I've found to be able to work with the decision tree itself:

```py
#get the pipeline back out, as you've done earlier, this changed to [3] because of the categorical encoders
ml_pipeline = pipeline.stages[3]

#saves the model so we can get at the internals that the scala code keeps private
ml_pipeline.save("mymodel_test")

#read back in the model parameters
modeldf = spark.read.parquet("mymodel_test/data/*")

import networkx as nx


#select only the columns that we NEED and collect into a list
noderows = modeldf.select("id","prediction","leftChild","rightChild","split").collect()


#create a graph for the decision tree; you Could use a simpler tree structure here if you wanted instead of a 'graph'
G = nx.Graph()

#first pass to add the nodes
for rw in noderows:
    if rw['leftChild'] < 0 and rw['rightChild'] < 0:
        G.add_node(rw['id'], cat="Prediction", predval=rw['prediction'])
    else: 
        G.add_node(rw['id'], cat="splitter", featureIndex=rw['split']['featureIndex'], thresh=rw['split']['leftCategoriesOrThreshold'], leftChild=rw['leftChild'], rightChild=rw['rightChild'], numCat=rw['split']['numCategories'])

#second pass to add the relationships, now with additional information
for rw in modeldf.where("leftChild > 0 and rightChild > 0").collect():
    tempnode = G.nodes()[rw['id']]
    G.add_edge(rw['id'], rw['leftChild'], reason="{0} less than {1}".format(features[tempnode['featureIndex']],tempnode['thresh']))
    G.add_edge(rw['id'], rw['rightChild'], reason="{0} greater than {1}".format(features[tempnode['featureIndex']],tempnode['thresh']))
```

Now let's build a function to work with the all this stuff
Note: this could be written more cleanly

```py
#function to parse the path based on the tagvalue and it's corresponding features
def decision_path(tag2search):
    wanted_row = transformed_pipeline.where("tagvalue = "+str(tag2search)).collect()[0]
    wanted_features = wanted_row['features']
    start_node = G.nodes()[0]
    while start_node['cat'] != 'Prediction':
        #do stuff with categorical variables
        if start_node['numCat'] > 0:
            feature_value = wanted_features[start_node['featureIndex']:start_node['featureIndex'] + start_node['numCat']]
            #this assumes that you'll name all your cat variables with the following syntax 'ball' -> 'ballVec' or 'wall' -> 'wallVec'
            feature_column = features[start_node['featureIndex']]
            original_column = feature_column[:-3]
            valToCheck = [x[original_column] for x in transformed_pipeline.select(feature_column, original_column).distinct().collect() if np.all(x[feature_column].toArray()==feature_value)][0]

            if (valToCheck == wanted_row[original_column]) :
                print("'{0}' value of {1} in [{2}]; ".format(original_column, wanted_row[original_column], valToCheck))
                start_node = G.nodes()[start_node['leftChild']]
            else:
                print("'{0}' value of {1} in [{2}]; ".format(original_column, wanted_row[original_column], valToCheck))
                start_node = G.nodes()[start_node['rightChild']]

        #path to do stuff with non-categorical variables
        else:
            feature_value = wanted_features[start_node['featureIndex']]
            if feature_value > start_node['thresh'][0]:
                print("'{0}' value of {1} was greater than {2}; ".format(features[start_node['featureIndex']], feature_value, start_node['thresh'][0]))
                start_node = G.nodes()[start_node['rightChild']]
            else:
                print("'{0}' value of {1} was less than or equal to {2}; ".format(features[start_node['featureIndex']], feature_value, start_node['thresh'][0]))
                start_node = G.nodes()[start_node['leftChild']]

    print("leads to prediction of {0}".format(start_node['predval']))
```

Results take this form:

```py
[decision_path(X) for X in range(1,8)]
    'fall' value of 8.0 was greater than 6.0; 
    'ball' value of 0.0 was less than or equal to 1.0; 
    'ball' value of 0.0 was less than or equal to 0.0; 
        leads to prediction of 21.0

    'fall' value of 9.0 was greater than 6.0; 
    'ball' value of 1.0 was less than or equal to 1.0; 
    'ball' value of 1.0 was greater than 0.0; 
    'keep' value of 5.0 was less than or equal to 5.0; 
        leads to prediction of 31.0

    'fall' value of 10.0 was greater than 6.0; 
    'ball' value of 1.0 was less than or equal to 1.0; 
    'ball' value of 1.0 was greater than 0.0; 
    'keep' value of 6.0 was greater than 5.0; 
    'wall' value of a in [a]; 
        leads to prediction of 21.0

    'fall' value of 11.0 was greater than 6.0; 
    'ball' value of 3.0 was greater than 1.0; 
    'wall' value of a in [a]; 
        leads to prediction of 31.0

    'fall' value of 2.0 was less than or equal to 6.0; 
        leads to prediction of 51.0

    'fall' value of 6.0 was less than or equal to 6.0; 
        leads to prediction of 51.0

    'fall' value of 10.0 was greater than 6.0; 
    'ball' value of 1.0 was less than or equal to 1.0; 
    'ball' value of 1.0 was greater than 0.0; 
    'keep' value of 6.0 was greater than 5.0; 
    'wall' value of c in [c]; 
        leads to prediction of 21.0
```

Notes:

- If you want to stay exclusively in Spark-world you could use GraphFrames instead of networkx (I don't have that luxury :( )
- You can modify the phrasing as you wish
- If you need the impurity, impurityStats, or gain, those are all in the model information dataframe that gets saved
- I chose to work with the tree instead of parsing the `.toDebugString` because having access to the tree sounded more foundationally important (and expandable)

  - On that note, just looking at the .toDebugString AND the sklearn.decision_path outputs, I feel that these are more easily understandable/readable
- if you want to visualize the tree, checkout: https://github.com/tristaneljed/Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark/blob/master/DT.py
- I had found a pure Scala implementation at some point, but can't find that again right now :(
- I feel like I'm missing a test case with the "Not In" categorical, if someone wants to throw in what that row would look like, I can edit if I have to

Comment: Thank you for an outstanding answer !

Comment: Can you please explain contents of files(mymodel_test/data/*) or provide a link which describes this ?

Answer (score 2):

More efficient and interpretable solution using todebugString attribute of decision tree in pyspark is as follows:
Note : If you want details on below code, please check https://medium.com/@dipaweshpawar/decoding-decision-tree-in-pyspark-bdd98dcd1ddf

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date,datediff,lit,udf,sum,avg,col,count,lag
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,LongType,StructType,StructField,DateType,IntegerType,DoubleType
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit, avg, max, min
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType, DoubleType
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
import operator

import ast

operators = {
            ">=": operator.ge,
            "<=": operator.le,
            ">": operator.gt,
            "<": operator.lt,
            "==": operator.eq,
            'and': operator.and_,
            'or': operator.or_
        }

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ball': [0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3],
    'keep': [4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 7],
    'hall': [8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 6, 10, 11],
    'fall': [12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 12, 14, 15],
    'mall': [16, 17, 18, 10, 10, 16, 18, 10],
    'label': [21, 31, 41, 51, 51, 51, 21, 31]
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

f_list = ['ball','keep','mall','hall','fall']
 assemble_numerical_features = VectorAssembler(inputCols=f_list, outputCol='features',
                                                      handleInvalid='skip')

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label')

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assemble_numerical_features, dt])
model = pipeline.fit(df)
df = model.transform(df)
dt_m = model.stages[-1]

# Step 1: convert model.debugString output to dictionary of nodes and children
def parse_debug_string_lines(lines):
    
    block = []
    while lines:

        if lines[0].startswith('If'):
            bl = ' '.join(lines.pop(0).split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            block.append({'name': bl, 'children': parse_debug_string_lines(lines)})

            if lines[0].startswith('Else'):
                be = ' '.join(lines.pop(0).split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
                block.append({'name': be, 'children': parse_debug_string_lines(lines)})
        elif not lines[0].startswith(('If', 'Else')):
            block2 = lines.pop(0)
            block.append({'name': block2})
        else:
            break
    
    return block

def debug_str_to_json(debug_string):
    data = []
    for line in debug_string.splitlines():
        if line.strip():
            line = line.strip()
            data.append(line)
        else:
            break
        if not line: break
    json = {'name': 'Root', 'children': parse_debug_string_lines(data[1:])}
    return json

# Step 2 : Using metadata stored in features column, build dictionary which maps each feature in features column of df to its index in feature vector
f_type_to_flist_dict = df.schema['features'].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"]
f_index_to_name_dict = {}
for f_type, f_list in f_type_to_flist_dict.items():

    for f in f_list:
        f_index = f['idx']
        f_name = f['name']
        f_index_to_name_dict[f_index] = f_name


def generate_explanations(dt_as_json, df:DataFrame, f_index_to_name_dict, operators):

    dt_as_json_str = str(dt_as_json)
    cond_parsing_exception_occured = False

    df = df.withColumn('features'+'_list',
                            udf(lambda x: x.toArray().tolist(), ArrayType(DoubleType()))
                            (df['features'])
                        )
    # step 3 : parse and check whether current instance follows condition in perticular node
    def parse_validate_cond(cond: str, f_vector: list):

        cond_parts = cond.split()
        condition_f_index = int(cond_parts[1])
        condition_op = cond_parts[2]
        condition_value = float(cond_parts[3])

        f_value = f_vector[condition_f_index]
        f_name = f_index_to_name_dict[condition_f_index].replace('numerical_features_', '').replace('encoded_numeric_', '').lower()

        if operators[condition_op](f_value, condition_value):
            return True, f_name + ' ' + condition_op + ' ' + str(round(condition_value,2))

        return False, ''
        
# Step 4 : extract rules for an instance in a dataframe, going through nodes in a tree where instance is satisfying the rule, finally leading to a prediction node
    def extract_rule(dt_as_json_str: str, f_vector: list, rule=""):
        
        # variable declared in outer function is read only
        # in inner if not explicitly declared to be nonlocal
        nonlocal cond_parsing_exception_occured

        dt_as_json = ast.literal_eval(dt_as_json_str)
        child_l = dt_as_json['children']

        for child in child_l:
            name = child['name'].strip()

            if name.startswith('Predict:'):
                # remove last comma
                return rule[0:rule.rindex(',')]

            if name.startswith('feature'):
                try:
                    res, cond = parse_validate_cond(child['name'], f_vector)
                except Exception as e:
                    res = False
                    cond_parsing_exception_occured = True
                if res:
                    rule += cond +', '
                    rule = extract_rule(str(child), f_vector, rule=rule)
        return rule

    df = df.withColumn('explanation',
                        udf(lambda dt, fv:extract_rule(dt, fv) ,StringType())
                        (lit(dt_as_json_str), df['features'+'_list'])
                    )
    # log exception occured while trying to parse
    # condition in decision tree node
    if cond_parsing_exception_occured:
        print('some node in decision tree has unexpected format')

    return df

df = generate_explanations(debug_str_to_json(dt_m.toDebugString), df, f_index_to_name_dict, operators)
rows = df.select(['ball','keep','mall','hall','fall','explanation','prediction']).collect()

output :
-----------------------
[Row(ball=0, keep=4, mall=16, hall=8, fall=12, explanation='hall > 7.0, mall > 13.0, ball <= 0.5', prediction=21.0),
 Row(ball=1, keep=5, mall=17, hall=9, fall=13, explanation='hall > 7.0, mall > 13.0, ball > 0.5, keep <= 5.5', prediction=31.0),
 Row(ball=1, keep=6, mall=18, hall=10, fall=14, explanation='hall > 7.0, mall > 13.0, ball > 0.5, keep > 5.5', prediction=21.0),
 Row(ball=3, keep=7, mall=10, hall=11, fall=15, explanation='hall > 7.0, mall <= 13.0', prediction=31.0),
 Row(ball=1, keep=7, mall=10, hall=2, fall=15, explanation='hall <= 7.0', prediction=51.0),
 Row(ball=0, keep=4, mall=16, hall=6, fall=12, explanation='hall <= 7.0', prediction=51.0),
 Row(ball=1, keep=6, mall=18, hall=10, fall=14, explanation='hall > 7.0, mall > 13.0, ball > 0.5, keep > 5.5', prediction=21.0),
 Row(ball=3, keep=7, mall=10, hall=11, fall=15, explanation='hall > 7.0, mall <= 13.0', prediction=31.0)]

output of dt_m.toDebugString:
-----------------------------------
'DecisionTreeClassificationModel (uid=DecisionTreeClassifier_2a17ae7633b9) of depth 4 with 9 nodes\n  If (feature 3 <= 7.0)\n   Predict: 51.0\n  Else (feature 3 > 7.0)\n   If (feature 2 <= 13.0)\n    Predict: 31.0\n   Else (feature 2 > 13.0)\n    If (feature 0 <= 0.5)\n     Predict: 21.0\n    Else (feature 0 > 0.5)\n     If (feature 1 <= 5.5)\n      Predict: 31.0\n     Else (feature 1 > 5.5)\n      Predict: 21.0\n'

output of debug_str_to_json(dt_m.toDebugString):
------------------------------------
{'name': 'Root',
'children': [{'name': 'feature 3 <= 7.0',
   'children': [{'name': 'Predict: 51.0'}]},
  {'name': 'feature 3 > 7.0',
   'children': [{'name': 'feature 2 <= 13.0',
     'children': [{'name': 'Predict: 31.0'}]},
    {'name': 'feature 2 > 13.0',
     'children': [{'name': 'feature 0 <= 0.5',
       'children': [{'name': 'Predict: 21.0'}]},
      {'name': 'feature 0 > 0.5',
       'children': [{'name': 'feature 1 <= 5.5',
         'children': [{'name': 'Predict: 31.0'}]},
        {'name': 'feature 1 > 5.5',
         'children': [{'name': 'Predict: 21.0'}]}]}]}]}]}
```